# PHP query Changing a result of 1 to YES

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

I have a section of code where I call a set of results with a query and then email the results as a CSV. One column of my results return either a 1 or a 0. I would like it so that when the CSV is created it write a YES for the results with a 1 and No for the results returned as 0. This is only for one column so I couldn't use a str_replace as this would affect all the data (I'm not great at PHP so I may be wrong about that).

I have tried a few thing and none seem to work, below is the section of code a one method I tried:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

if ($row->Optin_Marketing == "1") {
$mark = 'YES';
}
else {
$mark = 'NO';
}

$row->Optin_Marketing = $mark;

      for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) { 
        $row = str_replace('"', '', $row);
        $row = str_replace('en ', '', $row);

        // clean up the data; strip slashes; replace double quotes with two single quotes 
        $data_rows .= $file["csv_contain"] . preg_replace('/'.$file["csv_contain"].'/', $file["csv_contain"].$file["csv_contain"], stripslashes($row[$i])) . $file["csv_contain"];
        $data_rows .= ($i < $columns-1) ? $file["csv_separate"] : '';
      } 
      $data_rows .= $this->csv_end_row; // add data row to CSV file 
    }
```

Any help on this would be gratefully received.

Thanks

My query:

```
$emailCSV->setQuery('SELECT
orderheader.ordernumber As Order_Number
, ccilog.orderid AS Order_ID
, ccilog.userid AS User_ID
, orderheader.billingcustomeremailaddress AS Customer_Email
, orderheader.billingcontactfirstname AS First_Name
, orderheader.billingcontactlastname AS Last_Name
, orderheader.billingcustomername AS Company
, orderheader.billingcustomeraddress1 AS Address_1
, orderheader.billingcustomeraddress2 AS Address_2
, orderheader.billingcustomeraddress3 AS Address_3
, orderheader.billingcustomercity AS City
, orderheader.billingcustomercounty AS County
, orderheader.billingcustomerpostcode AS Postcode
, users.sendmarketinginfo AS Optin_Marketing
FROM orderheader 
LEFT JOIN users ON orderheader.userid=users.id
LEFT JOIN ccilog ON orderheader.id=ccilog.orderid
LEFT JOIN orderitems ON ccilog.orderid=orderitems.orderid
WHERE ccilog.formattedpaymentdate >= "'.$start.'" AND ccilog.formattedpaymentdate <= "'.$end.'"
');
```

Comment: this code needs some formatting...

Comment: You don't need to repeat this rows again and again in loop .<br>
 $row = str_replace('"', '', $row);
 $row = str_replace('en ', '', $row);

<br>

Comment: I'm only a PHP starter really and the code does what I need it to do, apart from this problem I have. I'm sure that people would look at my code and think what a mess but I guess you have to start some where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in your mysql query:

```
SELECT u.fieldname, CASE WHEN u.OPTION IS 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'yes/no'
FROM tblName u;
```

Or you could do it as nickb has suggested.

EDIT:

To fit it into your query, you would replace this:

```
users.sendmarketinginfo AS
```

With this:

```
CASE users.sendmarketinginfo WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Optin_Marketing'
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include the query, as you can see it is large. How would I fit your answer into this?

Comment: hmmm, this just errors?? I tried canging the ' for " but still didn't work.

Comment: It ok, I've sorted the problem, it should have been: CASE users.sendmarketinginfo WHEN "1" THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END AS "Optin_Marketing"

Comment: If your column is a tinyint(1) then what I've posted will work. out of interest, what is your column type? Glad you've got it working. :-)

Comment: it is a tinyint(1) but still didn't work so not sure why. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Compare the integer value, like so:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result)) 
{
    $row['Optin_Marketing'] = ( intval( $row['Optin_Marketing']) == 1) ? "YES" : "NO";
    echo $row['Optin_Marketing']; // Must be YES or NO here
}
```

The above condenses the entire check and change into one line using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You were accessing the array as if it were an object (using `->` instead of `['']`).

Also, how can this work, since `$row` is an array, and `str_replace` expects a string? Not sure what you're trying to do, but you might need something like [array_map](http://php.net/array_map).

```
$row = str_replace('"', '', $row);
$row = str_replace('en ', '', $row);
```

Comment: I've just tried that but I still get a 1 and 0 returened? Where would I place it in the code?

Comment: @user981978 - Place is directly after your loop to return the results. I'll update my post.

Comment: It does display Yes No on the web but this is not carried over to the CSV file. $row = str_replace('"', '', $row); works fine so not sure why if it should't. I use this to remove 'en' from the start of a description that is retuned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't found a mysqli_fetch_array function on PHP, so, I'll just assume you meant [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), which judging by the name should do pretty much the same. You have two issues in your code, the first one is with the definition of fetch array:

> **mysql_fetch_array** — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a
>   numeric array, or both

Can be fixed like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 
   $marketingOption = $row["Optin_Marketing"];
```

If you call fetch_array, you should be getting an array, not an object, so act accordingly. You could just call [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) and do it like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
```

The second is well pointed by nickb, so I'll just skip it.
Hope I can help!

Comment: Corrected. He tries to get object from an array.

Comment: mysqli is the improved MySQL extension for PHP - It exists: see http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I use MySQLi so you need mysqli_fetch_array as mysql_fetch_array doesn't work with My SQLi